# make Xcode (xcodeproj) settings from command line/shell?

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, automation, continuous-integration

i would want to control (some of) the settings of an Xcode project from the command line interface (shell).

- are there any tools available for such a use case?
- is it possible at all?
- or does my request even not make sense at all ? :)

---

background: for some automation purposes within ContinuousIntegration i'd like to tweak some settings of the project at build time. for this i don't want to have to open the Xcode for making these by some *"clickety-click"* ... which would hinder the build automation anyway

Comment: This is a good question. I hvn't played  so much but you can do a lot in shell script , like writing shell script for making archive of project etc. Just open the terminal  and type this :  xcodebuild --help . A lot of options are present there.

Comment: yeah, creating the IPA package from command line with 'xcrun...' isn't an issue :) however: i want to be able to tweak the settings to the needs as the 'xcodeproj' from the SCM repository doesn't have these (and is anyway "controlled" by somebody else)